Mediapipe hand tracking is very slow?
So I'm trying to use Mediapipe with Python to track my hands.
I followed the documentation from this google dev website

https://ai.google.dev/edge/mediapipe/solutions/vision/hand_landmarker/python

and this website

https://colab.research.google.com/github/googlesamples/mediapipe/blob/main/examples/hand_landmarker/python/hand_landmarker.ipynb#scrollTo=s3E6NFV-00Qt&uniqifier=1

But when I run the program it's very laggy, like 2 or 3 fps
CPU usage is about 10% and GPU around 3% when running. It doesn't look like a memory leak either.
Maybe there's a blatantly obvious error but I really don't know...
Thanks in advance!
import mediapipe as mp
from mediapipe import solutions
from mediapipe.framework.formats import landmark_pb2
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

BaseOptions = mp.tasks.BaseOptions
HandLandmarker = mp.tasks.vision.HandLandmarker
HandLandmarkerOptions = mp.tasks.vision.HandLandmarkerOptions
HandLandmarkerResult = mp.tasks.vision.HandLandmarkerResult
VisionRunningMode = mp.tasks.vision.RunningMode

mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

MARGIN = 10  # pixels
FONT_SIZE = 1
FONT_THICKNESS = 1
HANDEDNESS_TEXT_COLOR = (88, 205, 54) # vibrant green

#This function is copied from the documentation. The error could lie in this function but then the google employees have to update their code.

def draw_landmarks_on_image(rgb_image, detection_result):
   hand_landmarks_list = detection_result.hand_landmarks
   handedness_list = detection_result.handedness
   annotated_image = np.copy(rgb_image)

  # Loop through the detected hands to visualize.
   for idx in range(len(hand_landmarks_list)):
     hand_landmarks = hand_landmarks_list[idx]
     handedness = handedness_list[idx]

    # Draw the hand landmarks.
     hand_landmarks_proto = landmark_pb2.NormalizedLandmarkList()
     hand_landmarks_proto.landmark.extend([
       landmark_pb2.NormalizedLandmark(x=landmark.x, y=landmark.y, z=landmark.z) for landmark in hand_landmarks
     ])
     solutions.drawing_utils.draw_landmarks(
       annotated_image,
       hand_landmarks_proto,
       solutions.hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS,
       solutions.drawing_styles.get_default_hand_landmarks_style(),
       solutions.drawing_styles.get_default_hand_connections_style())

    # Get the top left corner of the detected hand's bounding box.
     height, width, _ = annotated_image.shape
     x_coordinates = [landmark.x for landmark in hand_landmarks]
     y_coordinates = [landmark.y for landmark in hand_landmarks]
     text_x = int(min(x_coordinates) * width)
     text_y = int(min(y_coordinates) * height) - MARGIN

    # Draw handedness (left or right hand) on the image.
     cv.putText(annotated_image, f"{handedness[0].category_name}",
                 (text_x, text_y), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX,
                 FONT_SIZE, HANDEDNESS_TEXT_COLOR, FONT_THICKNESS, cv.LINE_AA)

   return annotated_image

def draw_and_open_window(result: HandLandmarkerResult, output_image: mp.Image, timestamp_ms: int):

    annotated_image = draw_landmarks_on_image(output_image.numpy_view(), result)
    
    cv.imshow("newwindow", annotated_image)
        
    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        exit()
    
        
options = HandLandmarkerOptions(
#path is correct, i removed it for the post
    base_options=BaseOptions(model_asset_path='C:/etc/etc'),
    running_mode=VisionRunningMode.LIVE_STREAM,
    result_callback=draw_and_open_window
    )

landmarker = HandLandmarker.create_from_options(options)

#4 is the correct camera
cap = cv.VideoCapture(4)

timestamp_ms = 0
    
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break

    mp_image = mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB, data=frame)

    timestamp_ms += 1

    landmarker.detect_async(mp_image, timestamp_ms)
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows```
   
    

